# How to modify this function to accept the return in three different variables?

Tags: python, subprocess, yield

I have a function like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

def find_remote_files(hostspec):
    cmdline = ["rsync", "-e", "ssh", "-r", hostspec]
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull)
        try:
            for entry in proc.stdout:
                items = entry.strip().split(None, 4)
                if not items[0].startswith("d"):
                    yield items[4]
                    yield items[1]
                    yield items[2]
            proc.wait()
        except:
            # On any exception, terminate process and re-raise exception.
            proc.terminate()
            proc.wait()
            raise
```

This function returns three different things, I want to store that in three different variables like:

```
a, b, c = find_remote_date('username', 'password')
# a should hold yield items[4]
# b should hold yield items[1]
# c should yield items[2]
```

I get following error when I try to do that:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Why do you think that `yield` is better than `return` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return a tuple:

```
return items[4], items[1], items[2]
```

Which will cause the assignments to `a`, `b` and `c` that you require.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the syntax of the code above, its fairly common and straightforward. Does the error specifically reference this line of code as invalid?

Comment: Used your code to get a value in loop like this: a, b, c = [(i, j, k) for i, j, k in find_remote_files('source', 'password')]
print a  ------ But I get this error "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Answer (score 0):

You're probably thinking that the function breaks after you yield the objects. It doesn't. So the for-loop will continue, possibly yielding more values.

You can put a `return` after the yield statements so the function breaks, or even just return all the three values at once in a tuple by doing `return (items[4], items[1], items[2])`

Comment: File "/home/zurelsoft/Documents/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/functions.py", line 151
    return items[4], return items[1], return items[2]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user2545177 Only one `return` is needed. Try: `return (items[4], items[1], items[2])`